# How to use mysql SELECT query in a INSERT function on Sequalize

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I would like to use the following MYSQL Query on Sequalize. How i can make it possible?

```
INSERT INTO data_tree (parent_id, child_id, depth)
    SELECT parent_id, NEW.id, depth + 1)
    FROM data_tree
    WHERE child_id = NEW.parent_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as using:

```
sequelize.query(yourQuery).spread((result, meta) => {
  // handle result
});
```